# Reading one word at a time from input stream into char array?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get my program to reads words one at a time until the word "done" is detected. However, I can't seem to get the syntax right, first as you can see I used the getline function which reads the entire line. But that is not what I want ideally, so I decided to try using cin.get because I know it only reads input until a space or \n is encountered. Sadly, this fails after one traversal, making me enable to input anything...Below is my source code.

My source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char ch[256];
    std::cout << "Enter words\n";
    std::cin.get(ch, 256);
    while(strcmp(ch, "done")!=0)
    {
        std::cin.getline(ch, 256); // this reads the entire input, not what I want
        // std::cin.get(ch, 256); this line doesn't work, fails after one traversal

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Example run:

User enters : Hello there, my name is done

My program would then read each word at a time into the char array and then my test condition in the while loop checks it if it works.

As of now that doesn't work, because I am using getline, which reads the entire string and it only stops if I type the string "done" by itself..

Comment: Why not use std::string instead of a char array? and then do `cin >> word`

Comment: If your're going to use C++, then use it.'

Comment: My textbook C++ Primer Plus says I have to use a char array..

Comment: Then it's a bad textbook.

Comment: It's part of the end of chapter programming exercises, but other than that I have tried to loop the cin.get to read one word at a time, but after oen traversal I get stuck and it disallows me to input anything.

Comment: @AlanStokes Maybe it's an exercise to undertsand what's happening?

Comment: is I use the string class and do cin >> word, wouldn't that read the entire sentence?

Comment: @TakShing no, `cin >> word` will stop at first white space

Answer (score 1):

The difference between `std::istream::getline()` and `std::istream::get()` (the `char` array version) is that the latter does not extract the terminating character while the former does. If you want to read formatted and stop at the first space you'd use the input operator. When using the input operator with a `char` array make sure that you set up the array's width because otherwise you create a potential overflow (and attack vector) for your program:

```
char buffer[Size]; // use some suitable buffer size Size
if (std::cin >> std::setw(sizeof(buffer)) >> buffer) {
    // do something with the buffer
}
```

Note that this input operator stops reading when it either reaches a space or the buffer is full (where one `char` is used for the null terminator). That is, if your buffer is too small for a word and it end in `"done"` you may end up detecting the end string although it isn't really there. It is easier to use `std::string`:

```
std::string buffer;
if (std::cin >> buffer) {
    // do something with the buffer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char ch[256];
    std::cout << "Enter words\n";
    std::cin.get(ch, 256);
    std::string cont;

    while (cont.find("done") == std::string::npos)
    {
        cont = ch;

        std::cin.getline(ch, 256); // this reads the entire input


    }




    return 0;
}
```

using string is way easier!

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: Your code omits the case where OP wants to enter another line after the 1st has been processed.

Comment: sorry this should fix it.. look below

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char ch[256];
    std::cout << "Enter words\n";

    std::string cont;

    while (cont.find("done") == std::string::npos)
    {



        std::cin.getline(ch, 256); // this reads the entire input
        cont = ch;

    }




    return 0;
}
```